# Implementing For loop in open cv?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I want to implement similar loop in open cv.This code is done in Matlab .As i am new to open cv.I dont know how to proceed.Can Anyone give me ideas  to do this in C++

```
for m=1:10
 for n=1:20
    for l=1:Ns
       for k=1:Ns
            Y(l,k)=image1(m-Ns+l-1,n-Ns+k-1);
            DD(l,k)=image2(m-Ns+l-1,n-Ns+k-1);               
       end
    end  
  e=Y-DD ;     
 end
end
```

here Image1 and image2 are 300*300 pixel in size. Y ,DD,image1,image2 al are mat images.

Comment: in which programming language? c++?

Comment: Ya i want to implement in c++.i have edited the question :)

Comment: What do the 2 outer loops achieve? The results are only stored for m = 20 and n = 20.

Comment: There is a small code after the inner two loop.this 5*5 block are run all through out the image.Here Ns=5.

Comment: do you know how to implement a general `for loop` in C++ and only need to know how to access a pixel in OpenCV, or do you have absolutely no experience with C++? In the latter case you should definitely learn some basic C++ before trying to convert Matlab code to C++ ;)

Answer (score 0):

In OpenCV, the images can be represented as either `Mat` or `IplImage`. Your question does not specify the type of the image.

**If IplImage:**

```
IplImage *img;
unsigned char *image = (unsigned char*)(img->imageData);
int imageStride = img->widthStep;
pixData = image[xCount + yCount*imageStride];
```

**If Mat:**

```
Mat img;
unsigned char *image = (unsigned char*)(img.data);
int imageStride = img.step;
pixData = image[xCount + yCount*imageStride];
```

`pixData` will contain that data at `(xCount, yCount)`. You could use this understanding in the for loop.

As you already know the logic, I am mentioning only on how to access data from a particular point in an image.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way in OpenCV to access pixels in a for loop is:

```
cv::Mat rgbImage;
cv::Mat grayImage;
for ( int i = 0; i < rgbImage.rows; ++i )
  {
    const uint8_t* rowRgbI = rgbImage.ptr<uint8_t> ( i );
    const uint8_t* rowGrayI = grayImage.ptr<uint8_t> ( i );
    for ( int j = 0; j < rgbImage.cols; ++j )
      {
        uint8_t redChannel = *rowRgbI++;
        uint8_t greenChannel = *rowRgbI++;
        uint8_t blueChannel = *rowRgbI++;

        uint8_t grayChannel = *rowGrayI++
      }
  }
```

Depending whether your image is one or more channels you can modify the code above.

If you want to implement window sliding, you could do something like this:

```
cv::Mat img;
int windowWidth = 5;
int windowHeight = 5;
for ( int i = 0; i < img.rows - windowHeight; ++i )
  {
    for ( int j = 0; j < img.cols - winddowWidth; ++j )
      {
        // either this
        cv::Mat currentWindow = img(cv::Range(j, i), cv::Range(j + windowWidth, i + windowHeight));
        // perform some operations on the currentWindow

        // or do this
        getRectSubPix(img, cv::Size(windowWidth, windowHeight), cv::Point2f(j, i), currentWindow));
        // perform some operations on the currentWindow
      }
  }
```

You can read more about [getRectSubPix()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#getrectsubpix).

Comment: thanks for the answer.what my intention is that i need to excess first 5*5 block from each image and perform an operation.after that next 5*5 pixel and so on.